# Splunk: Show all the ids that are present in different events

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

My data is as follows:

```
event_A: { [-]
     processingTimeMillis: 2178
      event_A_recipients: [ [-]
       id1,
       id2,
       id3,
       id4,
     ]
   }
   eventType: event_A

event_B: { [-]
     processingTimeMillis: 2178
      event_B_recipients: [ [-]
       id1,
       id3,
     ]
   }
   eventType: event_B

event_B: { [-]
     processingTimeMillis: 2178
      event_B_recipients: [ [-]
       id2
     ]
   }
   eventType: event_B
```

Above is an example of what my source data looks like. There are two types of events, event_A and then event_B (json data). I am trying to list out all the ids that have an event_A associated with them, but not event_B. I tried using spath and sub-searches but nothing worked so far.

The above data should out id4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this seems quite tricky (of course the last time I said that someone else came along and answered it way more easily).  My way of doing this is:

- first you need to do a `transaction` to get all the events into one.
- then you need to `mvexpand` it on a copy of A's ids.
- then you can `mvappend` a copy of B's ids with the value of the expanded value of A's ids. (this doesn't add it if it already existed)
- then you can make a variable that is either `null()` or value of the expanded value of A's ids depending on the `mvcount`.
- then you can `stats` the values back into one event

Here is a run anywhere example:

```
| makeresults
| eval JSON="{\"event_A\":{\"processingTimeMillis\":\"2178\",\"event_A_recipients\":[\"id1\",\"id2\",\"id4\"]},\"eventType\":\"event_A\"}|{\"event_B\":{\"processingTimeMillis\":\"2178\",\"event_B_recipients\":[\"id1\",\"id3\"]},\"eventType\":\"event_B\"}|{\"event_B\":{\"processingTimeMillis\":\"2178\",\"event_B_recipients\":[\"id2\"]},\"eventType\":\"event_B\"}"
| eval JSON=split(JSON,"|")
| mvexpand JSON

| spath input=JSON
| rename event_A.event_A_recipients{} as A
| rename event_B.event_B_recipients{} as B

| eval id=""
| transaction id

| eval A_copy=A
| mvexpand A_copy

| eval C=mvdedup(mvappend(B,A_copy))
| eval matches=if(mvcount(C)>mvcount(B),null(),A_copy)

| table _time A B matches
| stats values(*) as * by _time
```